# Error in Entity Framework Seed Method Only When Not Printing Debugging Statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In our Entity Framework 6 seed method, we're setting user preferences to default values. We had a lot of issues getting stuff to work correctly, so we started printing debugging statements to a file. Now, however, if we remove the debugging lines, we get an exception.

Here is the code:

```
                // Get the preferences. 
                Preferences prefs = context.Preferences.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user.Id);

                using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"C:\myFile.txt"))
                {
                    //foreach (PropertyInfo prop in prefs.GetType().GetProperties())
                    //    write.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} = {prop.GetValue(prefs)}");

                    prefs.ColumnIds = defaultColumnIds;
                    prefs.Columns = defaultColumns;
                    prefs.CategoriesOnYAxis = true;
                    prefs.TabHorizontal = true;
                    prefs.OnlyAssignedToUser = true;

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
```

If we uncomment that For loop, then the seed method runs fine. With the for loop commented out, we get the following exception:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

In this example, the User object is 1-1 to the Preferences object, with Preferences having a foreign key to the User table.

We can even take out the stream writer and loop through the properties to the console, and as long as that loop is there the seed method runs correctly. As soon as it's gone, we get the error.

Comment: Do either of Preferences.ColumnIds or Preferences.Columns reference other entities? I don't see anything suspicious or unusual in the code you posted. Can you debug this code and access the EF ChangeTracker and see what the state of Preferences is? I'd expect it to be Modified, but that error might indicate it believes it's in another state.

Comment: The Preferences table references a table of Columns. If we take out the set on the ColumnIds, the seed runs fine, with and without the loop.

When we check the EF state for Added, Modified, or Deleted preferences BEFORE we set the properties, we get false with and without the For loop. If we check those states AFTER we set the properties, then we get false with and without the loop. So the state is always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a guess what might be happening here. I think this is your problem:

`prefs.ColumnIds = defaultColumnIds;
prefs.Columns = defaultColumns;`

I assume these are backed by the same field in your database? So you're setting both the Column entities as well as the ColumnId primary keys? You don't need to set both (though it *should* work).

I bet if you remove the assignment to `prefs.Columns` (and leave out the debug code), your code will start to work. The issue is `defaultColumns`. What's in there? Column entities - but are those entities attached to the current DbContext? (Your code doesn't show how they come into being)

When you fetch your prefs with `context.Preferences.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user.Id);`, you're asking EF for a Preference entity, but by default EF won't eager-load navigation properties (like those Column entities). Conversely, if you have a bunch of Column entities but they haven't been explicitly attached to (or fetched using) the current DbContext, EF will think those Columns are new, and that relationship might not be mapped in a way that EF can insert new Columns (which you don't want to happen, anyway).

When your debug code runs, `prefs.GetType().GetProperties()` is enumerating all the properties in the Preference, which I think EF is then lazy loading. When you remove the loop, it no longer enumerates then, so all the Preference's navigation properties didn't get pre-loaded.

There are a few ways you can go about this:

- If you're absolutely certain all those `defaultColumnIds` are already in the database when you run the Seed method, then set only `ColumnIds` and call it a day. It will match the entities in the database when it executes your query, and as long as the expected foreign keys are there you're fine.
- Fetch the `defaultColumns` from the context as soon as you open the context, or, if you defined them in code, attach them to the ChangeTracker before you call SaveChanges.